# Why is my loop infinite?

Tags: java

This is the 2nd out of 3 classes in my code and I'm not sure if it will work although Im not sure why Its on an infinite loop? I'm trying to make this game work so everytime a bet is either won or lost it affects my game so for one the pot is zero the game will end. It doesnt seem to be working although, any suggestions?

import java

```
.util.Scanner;


public class Game {
    public int potAmount = 50;
    public int betAmount= 0;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public void displayPot(){
        System.out.println("Your current pot is "+potAmount+"");
    }
    public void getbetamountfromuser(){
        System.out.println("Enter your bet amount:");
        betAmount = input.nextInt();
        potAmount= potAmount - betAmount;
    }

    public void playgame(){
        while( potAmount > 0) {
            Die Die1 = new Die();
            Die Die2 = new Die();
            Die Die3 = new Die();
            Die1.rollDice();
            Die2.rollDice();
            Die3.rollDice();
            Die1.Getdie();
            Die2.Getdie();
            Die3.Getdie();
            System.out.println("Your die are: "); 
            Die1.displayDice();
            System.out.print( " and ");
            Die2.displayDice();
            System.out.print( " and ");
            Die3.displayDice();
            int Totaldice=Die1.Getdie()+Die2.Getdie()+Die3.Getdie();


            if (Totaldice>=12){
                System.out.print("You WIN...your bet back");
            }

            else if (Totaldice<12){
                System.out.print("You LOSE....your bet ");
            }
            if (Die1==Die2 ){
                System.out.print("You WIN....double your bet");
                if (Die2==Die3 ){
                    System.out.print("You WIN....double your bet");
                    if (Die1==Die3 ){
                        System.out.print("You WIN....double your bet");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you change potAmount **within the loop**? If you don't change it inside of the loop, how does the loop know when to stop? Do you ever call `getbetamountfromuser()`, the method that reduces potAmount?

Comment: `==` tests **references**.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you change the value of `potAmount`, it will always be `> 0`, causing the loop to run infinitely.

Comment: So how will I add that in my loop? in my if or if else statements?

Comment: potAmount changes whenever the user wins a bet.  So wherever in your code someone wins, make sure that your subtract the amount that they won from potAmount.

Comment: Ok so I updated that I think? How do I show you if I did? and the other thing is , after each bet I would like to start a new bet with the new remaining pot? does that make sense to you?

Comment: if (Totaldice>=12){
    System.out.print("You WIN...your bet back.");
    potAmount = potAmount;   
    }
   else if (Totaldice<12){
    System.out.print("You LOSE....your bet. ");
    potAmount = potAmount - betAmount;

Comment: Try to edit the code in your question, it'll be easier to see

Comment: I wrote a little game like this long ago. It was kinda fun.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the loop changes `potAmount` - so, `potAmount` never becomes 0, so the loop keeps looping.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a game like that long ago and still have this. Since  our game are very similar you can use this to help you debug. I can provide the OOP version later if you want.

```
/**This program is a dice rolling game which asks a user to enter their bet amount, then it rolls the dice then based on these rules: 
 * If their roll is doubles - their bet amount doubles and gets added to their pot.
 * If their roll is 7 or 11 in total – then they win their bet amount and that amount will be added to their pot
 * If they're  roll is 5 or less or 10 or greater – then stay even otherwise they'll lose their bet and that bet amount gets subtracted from their pot
 */

import java.util.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 *
 * @author Tatakai
 */
public class DieGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pot = 100;
        // Array for first and second die are declared and instantialized here
        // with each having 6 elements.
        int[] firstDie = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] secondDie = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        while (true) {

            // Random element chooser for arrays
            int dieFace1 = firstDie[(int) (Math.random() * firstDie.length)];
            int dieFace2 = secondDie[(int) (Math.random() * secondDie.length)];
            int diceTotal = dieFace1 + dieFace2;

            System.out.print("Your current pot is " + formatter.format(pot)
                    + " enter your bet amount (0 to quit): ");
            int userIn = input.nextInt();

            while (userIn > pot) {
                System.out.print("Invalid bet amount, enter bet amount: ");
                userIn = input.nextInt();

            }
            if (userIn == 0) {
                System.out.print("You left the game with "
                        + formatter.format(pot));
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("you rolled a " + dieFace1 + " and " + dieFace2
                    + "\n");

            if (dieFace1 == dieFace2) {
                pot += userIn * 2;
                System.out.println("You Win Double!!");
                System.out.println("");

            } else if (diceTotal == 7 || diceTotal == 11) {
                pot += userIn;
                System.out.println("You win this bet!!");
                System.out.println("");

            } else if (diceTotal <= 5 || diceTotal >= 10) {
                System.out.println("You Stay even!!");
                System.out.println("");

            } else {
                pot -= userIn;
                System.out.println("You lose!!");
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```